# How to add inline css in html report using cucumber-html-reporter

Tags: html, css, cucumber

I am generating a html report using cucumber-html-reporter. I have to send this report in an email attachment, but when i do so, it removes all css and shows a simple text report.I researched a little and found out that i need to add inline css for the same. Is there any way to add inline css in report through cucumber-html-reporter?

Answer (score 0):

```html
**See if you have simple HTML elements you can simply write with "style".

<div style="border:1px solid #ddd;">
  This will work fine please try once adding like this.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Chandan, It worked when i downloaded the attachment .

Comment: No problem please mark the answer to correct so others can also use this.

Comment: How does that solve the problem? How would you be able to convert existing styles to inline style attribute?